# Return statement not giving output in proper format

Tags: python

I am trying to get the output from the return function but the output format is not people.

import link as l # it is python code where it checks the ACL flow

```
def t2e(src,dst,port,protocol):

    """
        acl output
        :param src : source ip
        :param dst : destination ip
        :param port : port
        :param protocol : protocol filed
        :args : source port
        :return : output
    """
    aclname = "t2e.jcl"
    dc = "abc"
    rpmName = "man-acl"
    ar.downloadlatestartifact(rpmName, aclDirName, dc)
    aclPath = "".join([aclDirName, f"/opt/manual-acl/acls/{aclname}"])
    
    print ("output for {}".format(aclname.upper()): output(src, dst, port, protocol, aclPath})
    

def output(src,dst,port,protocol,aclPath,*args):
    """
        ACL output
        :param src : source ip
        :param dst : destination ip
        :param port : port
        :param protocol : protocol filed
        :param acl_path : acl path where it is stored
        :args : source port
        :return : hunter output
    """
    logger.info("flow is running against required acl")
    
  
    option = {'dport': port, 'proto': protocol, 'showallmatches': True}
    return l.link(src, dst, files=[aclPath], opts=option)
```

Actually, I get output as below when run my code, this is proper output

actual format

```
############ CHECKING FLOW ############
8.8.8.8 -> 101.11.24.56 Dest Port:  443 Source Port:  0 Protocol: tcp
############## ACL CHECK ##############
Processing file: /var/folders/z6/1h1wt5x92rl9y4fsvh2j8y1c0000gp/T/tmpihe16vau/opt/m-acl/acls/t2e.jcl- HIT!!
Link Rule number: 11
Rule name: term web
Source Address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Destination Address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Destination Port: 25,8443,9443
Source Port: 0
Protocol: tcp
Application: 
Wildcard: False
Action: PERMIT
```

but when I return the "return l.link(src, dst, files=[aclPath], opts=option)" I am getting output on the screen as below which is not in proper format.

so how to get output in the proper format as above when I use a return statement?

```
{'Hunter output for TRANSIT2EDGE.JCL': {'/var/folders/z6/1h1wt5x92rl9y4fsvh2j8y1c0000gp/T/tmpihe16vau/opt/m-acl/acls/t2e.jcl': [['term web-axm', '0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0', '25,53,80,81,443,4309,8443,9443', '0', 'tcp', True, False, '', '', False, False, '', '', '', None, 'cde01edef036a4182afec9a6b8c72d63f0f1a6cb2e7d66f7e36bb3918f0dd106']]}}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context? What is the problem? How to convert from the dictionary actually returned to the desired string? What are the `l` objects (`l.link` / `l.l`)? Additionally, is this code working as intended? Although syntactically correct, the `for ...: ... return ... else: ... return ...` part is really strange and doesn't seem like the logical/easy way to obtain the effects I imagine this part of the script to have.

Comment: l.link is another function where it checks the acl flow for given source ,destination and port and protocol.

sorry  'l.l '  is typo, it is also l.link


i am importing the link function as l

Comment: If it is only a function which checks, am I right in assuming that the function you wish to modify is the `t2e` one? Also, you haven't addressed my other questions, namely on the context, whether it is only the conversion from dictionary to string you struggle with, and whether the code really works as intended.

Comment: yes, its t2e function which checks the acl flow with the helo of other module called l.link.

it is only conversion from dictionary to string. this code is working when with print the output but when i use return statement the output is improper format

Comment: Could you give us the type of `l`, as well as a reproducible example of the behaviour?